# User's name not showing in multiplayer godot waiting room

Tags: game-development, multiplayer, godot

so i was following a multiplayer godot tutorial on YouTube by ruyuse everything worked well (the server) until i got to the waiting room which is supposed to show the names of players joined, from this [image: the lobby] to this [image: the waiting room] but when i try mine  the lobby is the same but the waiting room ends up like this [image: my waiting room] i know there is something of but its my first time making a multiplayer game so pls help.

This is my server side:

server.gd

```
func _ready():
    start_server()
    
func start_server():
    network.create_server(port, max_players)
    get_tree().set_network_peer(network)
    network.connect("peer_connected", self, "_player_connected")
    network.connect("peer_disconnected", self, "_player_disconnected")
    
    print("server started")
    
func _player_connected(player_id):
    print("Player: " + str(player_id) + " Connected")
    
func _player_disconnected(player_id):
    print("Player: " + str(player_id) + " Disconnected")
        
    
remote func send_player_info(id, player_data):
    players[id] = player_data
    rset("players", players)    
    rpc("update_waiting_room")
```

The client:

server.gd:

```
extends Node

const DEFAULT_IP = "127.0.0.1"
const DEFAULT_PORT = 3234

var network = NetworkedMultiplayerENet.new()
var selected_IP
var selected_port

var local_player_id = 0
sync var players = {}
sync var player_data = {}

func ready():
    get_tree().connect("network_peer_connected", self,"_player_connected")
    get_tree().connect("network_peer_disconnected", self,"_player_disconnected")
    get_tree().connect("connection_failed", self,"_connected_fail")
    get_tree().connect("server_disconnected", self,"_server_disconnected")
    
func _connect_to_server():
        get_tree().connect("connected_to_server", self, "_connected_ok")
        network.create_client(selected_IP, selected_port)
        get_tree().set_network_peer(network)
        
func _player_connected(id):
    print("player: " + str(id) + "Connected")       
    
func _player_disconnected(id):
    print("player: " + str(id) + "Disconnected")        
    
func _connected_ok():
    print("successfully connected to server")   
    register_player()
    rpc_id(1, "send_player_info", local_player_id, player_data) 
    
func _connected_fail():
    print("failed to connect")  
    
func _server_disconnected():
    print("server disconnected")        
        
func register_player():
    local_player_id = get_tree().get_network_unique_id()
    player_data = Save.save_data
    players[local_player_id] = player_data
    
sync func update_waiting_room():
    get_tree().call_group("WaitingRoom", "refresh_players", players)
```

lobby.gd:

```
extends Control

onready var player_name = $CenterContainer/VBoxContainer/GridContainer/NameTextBox
onready var selected_IP = $CenterContainer/VBoxContainer/GridContainer/IPTextBox
onready var selected_port = $CenterContainer/VBoxContainer/GridContainer/PortTextBox
onready var waiting_room = $WaitingRoom
onready var ready_btn = $WaitingRoom/CenterContainer/VBoxContainer/ReadyButton


func _ready():
    player_name.text = Save.save_data["Player_name"]
    selected_IP.text = (Server.DEFAULT_IP)
    selected_port.text = str(Server.DEFAULT_PORT)
    
func _on_Join_button_pressed():
    Server.selected_IP = selected_IP.text
    Server.selected_port = int(selected_port.text)
    Server._connect_to_server()
    show_waiting_room()

func _on_NameTextBox_text_changed(new_text):
    Save.save_data["Player_name"] = player_name.text
    Save.save_game()

func show_waiting_room():
    waiting_room.popup_centered()

func _on_ReadyButton_pressed():
     ready_btn.disabled = true
```

waiting_room.gd:

```
extends Popup

onready var player_list = $CenterContainer/VBoxContainer/ItemList

func _ready():
    player_list.clear()

func refresh_players(players):
    player_list.clear()
    for player_id in players:
        var player = players[player_id]["Player_name"]
        player_list.add_item(player, null, false)
```

save.gd:

```
var save_data = {}

func _ready():
    save_data = get_data()
    
func get_data():
    var file = File.new()
    
    if not file.file_exists(SAVEGAME):
        save_data = {"Player_name": "Unnamed"}
        save_game()
    file.open(SAVEGAME, File.READ)  
    var content = file.get_as_text()
    var data = parse_json(content)
    save_data = data
    file.close()
    return(data)
    
func save_game():
    var save_game = File.new()
    save_game.open(SAVEGAME, File.WRITE)
    save_game.store_line(to_json(save_data))
```

and these are the errors i get on the server side (i realy don"t know what they mean)[image: error message]

I really hope this is not to long of a question because i really need help.
Thank you for reading.

sorry for the typos

Comment: Have you added Server as an Autoload?

Comment: oh it works now i only added the server as an autoload on the client side but i tried it now and it works well thanks

Comment: Can you add what you did to solve the problem as an answer to the question, then mark it as answered, so that it might help anyone else who searches for a similar problem?